# How to get data of a state in one step above

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner and I am learning React JS. I am making a demo project. I need a help there.

In my `app.js` there is routes `shop.js` and `review.js`. The data and states is in `shop.js`. Now how can I pass some states data on `review.js` from `shop.js`?

[Image](https://res.cloudinary.com/divcukylp/image/upload/v1647793621/images/Screenshot_2022-03-20_222459_jnebs3.png)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to child) via props, but such usage can be cumbersome for certain types of props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many components within an application. Context provides a way to share values like these between components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to lift the shared state up to their closest common ancestor (app.js).
please check
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html